# How to represent long sequence of bits in C?

Tags: c, base64, hex, bit-shift, bitstring

I'm trying to transform a string of hex to one long sequence of bits. This is part of challenge 1 in Cryptopals challenges (Convert hex to base64).

My idea was to convert each two chars in the string to one char of their numeric values (while multiply the first with 16) since |hex| = 4, |char|=8.

Then, mask the first 6 bits each time and convert them to base64.

The problem is that after the first 6 bits I need to shift left the all array 6 times - and apparently - i don't know how to do it.

So, as a start, are they any better approaches to represent the hex string as bits sequence?

And - how can I shift left the all array? I've seen here solutions dealing  with shifting each element and copying them - is this the simplest way?

This is what I've done so far - I added few extra steps for clarifying:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int elm = strlen(argv[1]) / 2;
    char *hashBits = malloc(sizeof(char) * elm);
    char a,b,c;
    for (int i = 0; i < elm; ++i) {
        a = charToBinary(argv[1][i*2]);   // Convert the char to its numeric value
        b = charToBinary(argv[1][i*2+1]);
        c = transformToChar(a,b);         // multiply the first with 16 and adds the second one
        hashBits[i] = c;
    }

    char base64Bits = 63 << 2;

    int elm64 = elm * 2 * 4 / 6;
    char *hashIn64Base = malloc(sizeof(char) * elm64);

    for (int j = 0; j < elm64; ++j) {
        hashIn64Base[j] = toBaseSixtyFour((hashBits[0] & base64Bits) >> 2); 
        hashBits = hashBits << 6;        //***This is obviously wrong but - how to do it?***//
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < elm64; ++k) {
        printf("%s", &hashIn64Base[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to represent bits you generally represent them either as characters or as just plain binary data. Which approach are you intending to use?

Comment: I tried characters but binary data would be much better

Comment: Then start bit bashing. You can do that with `x ||= 1 << n` where you want to set bit N.

Comment: @tadman: When did they introduce this compound assignment operator? it's not in C11. Plus it can invoke UB.

Comment: @olaf I'm using shorthand here.

Comment: regarding: `char *hashIn64Base = malloc(sizeof(char) * elm64);`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying by 1 has not effect,  and it clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're reading in the hex string looks like it should work.  You don't show `charToBinary` and `transformToChar`, but based on the comments next to the function calls you should end up with an array of bytes which the string will represent, so the method (assuming it's implemented correctly) is fine.

As for creating the base64 string, shifting the entire array by 6 bits for each base64 character is the wrong approach.

Take advantage of the fact that 8 * 3 == 6 * 4.  Take 3 bytes at a time and convert them into 4 base64 characters.  You can do this by looping through the array grabbing the current element as well as the next two to do the conversion, and increment your index by 3 on each iteration.

You'll need to check if the number of bytes is a multiple of 3.  If not, then the last loop iteration will need to deal with only having 1 or 2 bytes to work with.

When this happens, any extra base64 characters that aren't associated with any source bytes are set to `=`, and any extra bits in characters that do encode something are padded with 0.

For example, given the following two bytes:

```
00000000 11111111
```

You break it into 6 bit groups as follows:

```
000000 001111 111100
```

Note that the last group has extra 0's at the end.  So you'll end up with 3 base64 characters plus one `=`.

Given a single byte:

```
11111111
```

This is grouped as:

```
111111 110000
```

So you'll have 2 base64 characters plus 2 `=`.

When decoding, having 1 `=` at the end means you have 2 extra and having 2 `=` means you have 1 extra.

Comment: by the way, how to interpret the last 1 or 2 bytes as base64? 
And the question is in general: I guess every hash string would be a power of 2 so hex will always work - but base64 not... so what is the convention: do you pad with zeros? from the left or from the right?
Let's say i have hex string of 8 digits - i can change them into binary of 4 characters. So, I have now two bits extra for 5 base64 digits. Are they really extra? Are they the 2 msb's or the 2 lsb's?
Or I'm looking at this wrongly? Are there any conventions?
Thanks

Comment: @Mithrandir See my edit regarding how to handle extra bytes that aren't a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Base-64 encoding represents 3 bytes (24 bits) in 4 characters (representing 6 bits each).

So you want to take these 24 bits:

```
12345678 12345678 12345678
```

and turn them into these four chunks:

```
123456 781234 567812 345678
```

You can "mask off" certain bits using expressions like  `x & 0xfc` and `x & 0x03`.  You can shift bits left and right using `<<` and `>>`.  You can put two nonoverlapping bit sequences together using `|`.

Once you've got your 6-bit chunks, the usual way to map them to the characters of the Base-64 alphabet is to use them as indexes into an array:

```
char base64_alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
```

You've also got some extra work to do to handle the case that the input length is not an exact multiple of 3 bytes.

I don't want to spoil the fun of the challenge, so I'll leave the rest to you.